# Is it possible to set observable in 'click' binding?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

Is it possible to set observable in 'click' binding?

`<div data-bind="click:toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex(0)"`>

where toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex is an observable.

Comment: I'm shocked how people just answer this without telling its bad practice, its bad! Bad, bad, bad. The whole point of MVVM is to decouple the view from the view logic so it can be tested, reused etc.

Comment: As hacky as javascript is I wouldn't worry about "bad practice" aside from obvious coding mistakes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div data-bind="click: toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex.bind($data, 0)">
```

Comment: This answer calls that function on page load. Using `.bind` is the correct method.

Comment: @Cabloo, you are wrong, function will not be called on page load. But, using **bind** is more correct, you are wright.

Comment: @Alexander - the data-bind attribute is evaluated on page load. When the `bind` function is evaluated on page load, it returns a callback, which is what should be passed to click. You were passing the evaluated version of the function you meant to be passing as a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Writing "click: function(){...}" isn't the nicest solution. I believe this would be a bit better even tho it is a few more lines of code.

```
<div data-bind="click: resetIndex">....</div>
```

in your viewmodel define:

```
function resetIndex(){
    toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but i don't think it is a right choice:

```
<div data-bind="click:toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex.bind($data, 0)">
```

`Bind` allows to call your function (observable is a function) with particular value. First argument of bind is value for `this` object, second is the first parameter for function.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548048/anders) on this one...

> The whole point of MVVM is to decouple the view from the view logic so it can be tested, reused etc.

To manipulate data contained within the view-model in this way will work, however, not ideal.

```
<div data-bind="click: function() { toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex(0) }">
```

Knockout offers a cleaner way to implement this with an [unobtrusive event handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

In your example, you should do something like this...

```
<div id="clickme">...</div>
```

...and then include the following in your javascript

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(e) {
    ko.dataFor(this).toolbarBottomTabs_selectedIndex(0);
});
```

Comment: Or just add a function that does the same thing on the ViewModel maybe!? ;)

Comment: Absolutely.  I choose this method so I can group UI specific logic here and then make discrete calls to the ViewModel.

Comment: if you use the click binding KO will make sure its updated when the view is rerendered (items removed, added etc)

Comment: This is true. As we can't be sure what else may manipulate this element.  The same can be achieved for unobtrusive event handlers by using jQuery's $.on() method to handle the click.  I shall update my sample.

Comment: You are starting to reinvent the KO wheel ;) Just use the click binding and your set?

Comment: "Is it possible to set observable in 'click' binding?" was the question, not whether it was good/bad (READ: entirely subjective) practice